# Inserting int number, mysql

Tags: mysql, numbers, int

Im trying to insert a number, but got some troubles.

I got this number from a different website with crawl so i think its a string, but i tried inserting as string and no results...

```
$ljuga_in = "INSERT INTO lplayer VALUE( now(), '{$player[$m][2]}','{$player[$m][3]}', '{$player[$m][1]}' );";
```

when i `echo player[$m][2];`

i got the next: `160.000`

but this isnt 160, is 160000 and all what save me is 1, even if i put the field in data base as numeric with 15 numbers, i got 1 as result. I dont know how to fix the problem, any help would be considered.

Thanks forward!!

Comment: What is the datatype of the second column in your database table?

Comment: what is the table structure? are you using php too?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your string isn't what you thing it is: try echoing the query and see if it makes sense.  Consider changing your query string to something like the following:

I assume your using php?

```
$ljuga_in = "INSERT INTO lplayer VALUE( now(), '".$player[$m][2]."','".$player[$m][3]."', '".$player[$m][1]."' );";
```

Also confirm the datatypes of the fields in your mysql table.  If you try to write a string (non-numeric) to a field of datatype int, you won't get what you want saved in the table

lastly, you're query is vulnerable to mysql injection attacks...  you should probably fix that

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you replace your string with this?

```
$ljuga_in = 'INSERT INTO lplayer VALUE( now(), "'.$player[$m][2].'","'.$player[$m][3].'", "'.$player[$m][1].'" )';
```